# Не работает CAN шина на STM32F407

Tags: c, stm32

В режиме SILENT_LOOPBACK все работает как часы, при переходе в режим NORMAL и подключении к какой нибудь КАН шине других устройств, СТМ вообще игнорирует любые сообщения на шине... Перебрав разные скорости и не получив результата, тупо замкнул RX и TX стмки и попробовал отправлять сообщения самому себе, но безуспешно... В чем может быть проблема?

Код прерывания на прием:

```
    void HAL_CAN_RxCpltCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef* hcan){
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14);
  DATA[0] = hcan->pRxMsg->Data[0];
  DATA[1] = hcan->pRxMsg->Data[1];
  DATA[2] = hcan->pRxMsg->Data[2];
  DATA[3] = hcan->pRxMsg->Data[3];
  DATA[4] = hcan->pRxMsg->Data[4];
  DATA[5] = hcan->pRxMsg->Data[5];
  DATA[6] = hcan->pRxMsg->Data[6];
  DATA[7] = hcan->pRxMsg->Data[7];

  for(int i =0; i < 8; ++i) hcan->pRxMsg->Data[i] = 0;
    HAL_CAN_Receive_IT(&hcan1, CAN_FIFO0);  
}
```

Инициализация:

```
static void MX_CAN1_Init(void)
{

  hcan1.Instance = CAN1;
  hcan1.Init.Prescaler = 6;
  hcan1.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan1.Init.SJW = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan1.Init.BS1 = CAN_BS1_8TQ;
  hcan1.Init.BS2 = CAN_BS2_5TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TTCM = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.ABOM = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AWUM = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.NART = ENABLE;
  hcan1.Init.RFLM = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.TXFP = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}
```

И настройка фильтра:

```
  CAN_FilterConfTypeDef canFilterConfig;
  canFilterConfig.FilterNumber = 0;
  canFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
  canFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
  canFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000 << 5;
  canFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
  canFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000 << 5;
  canFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
  canFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_FIFO0;
  canFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
  canFilterConfig.BankNumber = 1;
  HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1, &canFilterConfig);   

  for(int i =0; i < 8; ++i) canRxBuffer.Data[i] = 0;
```

Comment: Здесь только инициализация CAN, а где инициализация портов ввода-вывода?

Comment: @maestro я за это время успел разобраться, причина: Сильное не соответствие моего КАН с КАНом устройства к которому я подключался)

Comment: Не забывайте, выводы CAN микроконтроллера нужно подключать к внешней микросхеме приёмопередатчика CAN, а уже его выводы - к другому устройству.